# WARNING: Tasa de mensajes IOPub superados jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, ipython

Hoy desperté con este `warning` en mi `notebook`. Me pide cambiar el valor de `--NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit`.

> Current values: NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit=1000.0 (msgs/sec)
>   NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

El problema radica supongo porque tengo muchos `output` en el `.ipynb`. ¿Cómo debería ajustarlo para que deje de enviar el `warning`?

> IOPub message rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop
>   sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change
>   this limit, set the config variable
>   `--NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit`.
>
> Current values: NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit=1000.0 (msgs/sec)
>   NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, según [este hilo](https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/1181), se trataría de un problema de `Jupyter` el  limite `iopub.data_rate` estaría configurado con un valor insuficiente. El problema estaría resuelto en la versión 5.2. Mientras tanto, como solución de compromiso puedes:

- Iniciar `Jupyter` así: `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10`
- O bien, crear un archivo de configuración mediante: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`, el cual se llamará `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, lo editas y modificas el valor de la clave `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`, lo descomentas si estuviera comentado y le agregas un valor más alto, por ej: `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000`

Fuente: [IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (when viewing image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image)